# undefined method `get' with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a problem with a very basic Rspec code, the same problem as the question 'undefined method `get' for #'.

But in my case none of the solutions given have worked for me!

I have my Rspec code at '/RailsProject/spec/controllers' and the code is:

```
require "../spec_helper"
describe "ApiMobile", :type => :controller do
    it "Log In" do
        get 'apiMobile/v0/logIn/test'
        expect(response).to be_success
    end
end
```

As you can see I've followed all the instructions but I still have the problem:

```
 1) ApiMobile Log In
 Failure/Error: get 'apiMobile/v0/logIn/test'
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x000000023b5ec8>
 # ./api_mobile_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Finished in 0.00056 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

I have missed something or similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have 'rspec/rails' required in your spec helper

Comment: after get specify the controller method as a symbol. for ideal way of defining specs, refer https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

Comment: Doing that it raises a new error:`require': cannot load such file -- rails/rspec (LoadError)

Comment: @BillyChan Are you sure this is the same problem you referred to? In the other question, they weren't getting `undefined method`. This seems like an issue with `rspec-rails` installation, although I haven't seen the confirmation from the OP yet.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, yes, that's right, you always caught me :) Oriol, sorry, me link is irrelevant.

Comment: How can I confirm that the installation is ok?

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered what was happening: Peter Alfvin was right, the fault was the isntallation.

I added at the Gemfile 'gem rspec' and at the command line typed 'rspec --init' after the 'bundle install'. But I also needed to add the gem 'rspec-rails' and type 'rails generate rspec:install'.

Now the get command works (I have another error but I think that is related to routes).